# Is there a way to open a File's Properties window that ISN'T Modal?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making an Explorer-type of app, and displaying the files, folders, and drives in a `TreeView` and a `ListView`, using the code from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/creating-an-explorer-style-interface-with-the-listview-and-treeview) tutorial, and have been playing around with it.

Now, I am creating the `ContextMenuStrip` for the `ListView`, and I have most of the kinks worked out. (Creating a new file, folder, zip, etc.)

But, I can't seem to figure out how to open a Properties Window that **is not Modal.**

I've tried using `ShellExecute` for opening the Properties Window, and it works fine - Except that the parent `Form` is still accessible. (e.g. I can resume focus by clicking it.)

When a normal `Form` is opened using `ShowDialog()`, it blocks any user interaction with the parent `Form`, until it has been closed. I want the Properties Window to have the same behavior.

I hope my question is clear :)

Comment: This sentence: *I can't seem to figure out how to open a Properties Window that is not Modal* appears to contradict the next *I want to open a Properties Window that has the same behavior as a MessageBox would*.

Comment: @Jimi - **Oh! I might've gotten a bit mixed up, there..**

Comment: Do you mean like with `Process.Start` or `ShellExecute`?

Comment: @Jimi I turned to `Process.StartInfo`, and it works fine, except that when I type `process.WaitForExit();` it throws an error, stating that `process` is not tied to any open processes, even though it _should be_.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested it, and the way to open the file properties window via ShellExecute is completely unusable on Win11, and I'm curious why the answer is all over the web, completely wrong. Using the 'SHObjectProperties' API will solve the problem, and while MSDocs mentions that the API may be removed soon, at least it is available for now. (2024/3/28)

Here's an example:
[github.com/OrgEleCho/CurvaLauncher/blob/main/src/CurvaLauncher/Apis/CommonApi.cs](https://github.com/OrgEleCho/CurvaLauncher/blob/main/src/CurvaLauncher/Apis/CommonApi.cs)